# Why do mechanical keyboards have 2x USB plugs? Ordinary keyboards only have one

Tags: usb, keyboards

Why do mechanical keyboards have 2x USB plugs? Ordinary keyboards only have one.

For example Logitech G G815 has 2x USB plugs, also the whole previous models. Why is that? I have tried it and it is enough to plug in one plug.

Comment: Hi Sybil! In the case of the G815 it's for USB passthrough; why Logitech went with this design over an internal hub, I'm not sure. That said, this is a question about existing hardware instead of a request for a recommendation, it is unfortunately off-topic for this site; you may get more help on Superuser.

Comment: Which ones? None of the Keychron mechanical keyboards have 2x USB plugs. The same for Rapoo, Cooler Master, and Ducky (for the latter, at least most don't).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned on their [site](https://www.logitechg.com/en-us/products/gaming-keyboards/g815-low-profile-rgb-mechanical-gaming-keyboard.html), one is a passthrough port.  So, you can plug something close by instead of at the PC.  And it not true that mechanical keyboards have 2X USB ports.

> **COMPATIBILITY**

- Windows® 7 or later
- macOS 10.11 or later
- 2x USB ports (1x keyboard, 1x USB passthrough port)